# Xamarin cross notification custom sound

Tags: android, ios, audio, xamarin.forms, notifications

I am using 

Xamarin + firebase notification for cross platform app 

**Need** 

To change the default notification sound 

**Expect** 

The sound changed, even if the app is colse. Which means I will assign a different tone for the notifications which come to this app 

**Coding** 
No need to write any code to play the sound or to trigger the on notofication recieved event at all 


**Current result**: 
I success to do this with IOS only, but faild with Android. 
Now I can recieve notification with custom sound even if the app is closed, without writting any code for this 


**My code** 
For IOS 
1- add this line to the notification payload  
"sound": "test.wav" 
only sound name with the extention 
2- add test.wav to IOS project under Resources as "BundleResource", or "Embedded Resource" 
3- send the notification, and do not care about "NotificationRecieved" event at all 
4- kill the app, and send the notification 
5- notification recieved with custom sound "test.wav" 
6- IOS accect "wav" or "caf" files only 

**For Android** 
Repeat the same with "wav" file, but with some changes like: 
1- the sound file add at Resources/raw as AndroidResource For Project.Droid 
2- try to change the payload to be: 
"sound": "test.wav" 
"sound": "test" 
"sound": "raw/test.wav" 
"sound": "raw/test" 
But never success to play the sound 

**Question** 
I am sure there is something wrong in the ("sound": "test.wav") format. 
I tested it with and without extention, 
I do not need to handle the sound by coding, I want to assign the tone exactly as done with the IOS project 

I expected IOS to be harder than Android! but at end it was easy 

Any help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I solved it.

For those who face the same problem I will post the solution.

For IOS, you can only pass the sound file name as I said before.

For Android, it is comples. I noticed that the app uses the default system sound for all notification which recieved in the background mode, closed, or killed app.

I went to the app settings, then I found a channel name "***Miscellaneous***" which used for such notifications.

The idea was how to change this channel sound?

If you create a channel with the same name, it will not work because you have to use channel name + channel ID.

I searched and finaly find the default channel id which is "***fcm_fallback_notification_channel***".

The second step was to create a channel with this name and id, in hope to override the system one.

I created this channel in the app start with the following code:

```
var importance = NotificationImportance.High;
var soundFileName = "sound";

NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel("fcm_fallback_notification_channel", "Miscellaneous", importance);
chan.EnableVibration(true);
chan.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;
chan.SetSound(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://com.myapp.test/raw/" + soundFileName), null);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan);
```

And it works as expected :)

Now I can recieve nottifications with the custom sound even if the app is closed, killed, or background mode.

I did not think that I can do this, finally.

Thanks for everyone.

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to accpet it asnwer after two days. It will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the Android, you should set the sound in `NotificationChannel`

```
var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default)
                          {
                              Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
                          };
var audioattributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder();
audioattributes.SetContentType(AudioContentType.Music);
audioattributes.SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification);
channel.SetSound(global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + this.ApplicationContext.PackageName + "/raw/app_sound"), audioattributes.Build());
```

**Note**: If you set it, please uninstall the app to alter sound settings, Check out these [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I lready tried this idea. It works only if the application is running (foreground) , and not working if the app is killed or (background). Any suggestion?

Comment: I noticed that my app uses a notification channel called "Miscellaneous" for the notifications come in the killd app. I can manually change the tone from app settings. Is there any way to do this from inside the app?